# Why is my HEAD ref failing to run on git?

Tags: git, git-commit

I know there are a lot of simiular issues that people have but my issue is a bit different. I don't know how but my standard built in Documents folder under my PC has a head reference to some weird branch that I know doesn't exist anymore. If it wasn't my built in Documents folder I would just copy all the files/folders in it and start a new one but I can't just delete and start a new one. So basically I need to find out how I can delete this head ref or make a new one. It's making it hard for me to start a new branch in a folder I am working on in Documents with the issue.

The following is a picture of my PC directory with an uncommitted symbol on the built in Documents folder. If you look down at the context menu at where it say's "Git Commit ->" there's some old branch I used only for a tutorial a year ago that doesn't exist anymore but I can't get it to go away. I believe I want to ref a new HEAD would be my solution but I don't know how.

[image]

Comment: If you don't need any of the git history you may be able to just delete the `.git` folder. What does `git fetch --all; git log --graph --all --decorate` show?

Comment: Used both git scripts in  *C:\User\Kirim\Documents>* and nothing showed. Like it was just blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can see branches by executing `git branch` and if there's is an unwanted branch just delete it executing `git branch -d <branch_name>`

or else you can remove your all git history by `rm -rf .git` and reinitialize your repo using `git init`

Comment: I used `git branch` in my Documents directory and I received the error: `fatal: Failed to resolve HEAD as a valid ref.`. Also, I do have files in this document I don't want to lose. I just want to make sure those files wouldn't be physically deleted if I just delete the git history.

Answer (score 0):

I had a strange error where my `.git` was starting in my Users repository on my C drive. I fixed this issue by deleting the `HEAD ref` file first, then deleting the `.git` file. Then started a new repository in Github and cloned that repository to my Online learning directory. Thanks for the help!